# Can't add SpecFlow item to project in Visual Studio 2012 Premium

Tags: visual-studio-2012, specflow

I installed SpecFlow v1.9.1 with Visual Studo 2012 Premium, but when I tried to add a new SpecFlow item to a class library project, I can't add a SpecFlow item because it's not on the list of items I can add.

After some search, I found SpecFlow is having problems with Visual Studio Express, but I'm using the Premium edition. I'll be suprised if SpedFlow does not support Premium version.

Comment: Im using SepcFlow 1.9.0 in VS 2010 Premium and SpecFlow 1.9.1 with VS2012 Pro with no issues. So I'd be surprised if there are any issues either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will work since its a VSIX package, but have you tried closing all VS windows and then from the VS command prompt

```
devenv /setup
```